# Invalid Artifacts path

Tags: node.js, ethereum, solidity, artifact, hardhat

*I am getting this error everytime pls look after it*

```
Error HH702: Invalid artifact path E:\Block Chain Projects\SET OOD\artifacts\contracts\MOOD.sol\Mood.json, its correct case-sensitive path is E:\Block Chain Projects\SET OOD\artifacts\contracts\Mood.sol\Mood.json
```

**THE ERROR**

```
async function main()
{
  const {deployers} =await  ethers.getSigners();
  const MOODCONTRACT = await ethers.getContractFactory('Mood');
  const moodcontract =await  MOODCONTRACT.deploy();
  console.log("the contract is deployed"+moodcontract.address);
}
main().then(
  ()=>process.exit(0)
).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
  process.exit(1);
})
```

**MY deploy.js file**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

contract Mood {
    string mood;
    function Setmood(string memory _mood) public {
        mood = _mood;
    }
    function Getmood() public view returns(string memory)
    {
        return mood;
    }
}
```

**My Mood.sol**
[look this if u want to see the files path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpzgU.png)

Answer (score 2):

given your attached picture it seems to be a case sensitive problem.
Check out the error information hardhat provides:

[image: hardhat errors]

see https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/errors.

Given your picture the contracts seems correct, did you change the name once from "MOOD.sol" to "Mood.sol".

If your contract itself has the name "Mood" (contract Mood {}) then it should be fine and you can try firing: `npx hardhat clean` and then try your `npx hardhat compile` again.

Comment: Yes I changed from MOOD. sol to mood.sol

Comment: So if the answer was correct, it would be nice, if you would tag it as correct answer. Have fun building

Answer (score 0):

I solved a looks like problem in hardhat...

- contracts\MOOD.sol\Mood.json =! Mood.sol // contract Mood {

i'll suggest try to rename:

- the contract file (Mood.sol)
- the contract name (contract Mood {})
- in deploy.ts const COG = await ethers.getContractFactory('Mood');

and as MichiMich says... run

- npx hardhat clean
- npx hardhat compile

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34420355)